# How to convert a date string zone oriented and hour string into datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have two strings one: `date='2021-12-30T23:00Z'` where Z means UTC timezone and 23:00 means hour. I also have an hour string `hour='3'`. What I want is to convert date to datetime object and add this hour string to date as a delta. In result I would get a datetime object with hour: `'2021-12-31T02:00Z'` I tried function datetime.datetime.fromisoformat() with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strftime` with their format.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date='2021-12-30T23:00Z'

date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
new_date = date + timedelta(hours=3)
new_date = new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
print(new_date)
```

Output:

> `2021-12-31T02:00Z`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


date = "2021-12-30T23:00Z"
hour = "3"

d = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z") + timedelta(hours=int(hour))
print(d)
```

output:

```
2021-12-31 02:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Thank, I also want the resulting date to be zone oriented

Comment: I added that to the formatting string. Changed the `Z` to `%z`.